# How to create multiple Streams dynamically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have this code which adds each character from a String to a Stream inside a timer creating this effect:

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: TextSpanStream(),
    ),
  );
}

class TextSpanStream extends StatefulWidget {
  TextSpanStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextSpanStreamState createState() => _TextSpanStreamState();
}

class _TextSpanStreamState extends State<TextSpanStream> {
  Timer? _timer;
  StreamController<String> _textShowController =
      StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => startBroadcast());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textShowController.close();
    _timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void startBroadcast() {
    String title = 'This is a title';
    int countLetter = 1;

    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
      _textShowController.add(title.substring(0, countLetter));
      countLetter++;
      if (countLetter == title.length + 1) {
        timer.cancel();
        countLetter = 1;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[900],
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black26,
          width: 400,
          child: StreamBuilder<String>(
            stream: _textShowController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(
                snapshot.hasData ? (snapshot.data ?? '') : '',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The thing is, instead of a single String, I want to perform this with RichText, where each TextSpan comes from a List of TextSpan with unknown length. This way, each TextSpan would have its own different style and would be animated in sequence (one stream after another).

In example:

```
List<TextSpan> allSpans = [TextSpan(text: 'This is a ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)), TextSpan(text: 'title', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))];
```

Is it possible to create a separate Stream for each TextSpan? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create TextSpan and send it via stream to be built.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Rich Text Animation',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Rich Text Animation'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamController<List<TextSpan>> _streamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();
  static const DELAY = Duration(milliseconds: 100); 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animate();
  }

  void _animate() {
    final _allSpans = [
      TextSpan(text: 'This is a ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      TextSpan(text: 'title', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
    ];
    Duration _delay = Duration(seconds: 1);
    _allSpans.forEach((span) {
      for (int i = 0; i < (span.text?.length ?? 0); i++) {
        Future.delayed(_delay, () {
          _streamController.add([
            ..._allSpans.sublist(0, _allSpans.indexOf(span)),
            TextSpan(text: span.text!.substring(0, i + 1), style: span.style)
          ]);
        });
        _delay += DELAY;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green.shade700,
        child: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<TextSpan>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(children: snapshot.data),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
            stream: _streamController.stream,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.animation),
        onPressed: () {
          _animate();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```